# how to handle new table columns in java code dynamically

Tags: java, database

First of all I am still not sure about posting this question here (As I did not find a relevant answer). I have a scenario, where a new column in a DB table will be introduced once in a while. So, with this I need to make changes in my controller/action classes to read/write this new column. So, I am looking for a way (if any) to accommodate this change in my java classes. i.e. whenever a new column is introduced, the java class should be able to read/write the values.

Thanks in advance.

Keerthi Kumar N

Comment: *new column in a DB table will be introduced once in a while*, every day ? every week ? every month ? every year ? If it is so frequent then, you need to concentrate on data modelling instead. If you are clear with requirement, then it can not be frequent.

Comment: Even if there are new columns unless you are displaying them and/or using them in you business logic, there should be no effect (assuming nullable columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ResultSetMetaData** class to get metadata of table.

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE");
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();

for(int i=1; i<=metadata.getColumnCount(); i++) 
    System.out.println(metadata.getColumnName(i));
```

But for this every time you need to check for the columns which is an overhead for the application.